# callbacks in sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, lightgbm

I want use callbacks and eval_set etc.
but i have a problem:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
import lightgbm
```

```
verbose = 100
params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    "n_estimators": 500,
    "verbose": 0
}
fit_params = {
    "eval_set": eval_dataset,
    "callbacks": [CustomCallback(verbose)]
}

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(lightgbm.LGBMClassifier(**params))
clf.fit(X_train, y_train,  **fit_params)
```

how i can hand over fit_params to my estimator? I get

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
---> 13 clf.fit(X_train, y_train,  **fit_params)

TypeError: OneVsRestClassifier.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eval_set'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per `scikit-learn`'s docs for `OneVsRestClassifier` ([link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.fit)), as of v1.4.0 additional `**fit_params` are only passed through to estimators' `fit()` methods if you've enabled what `scikit-learn` calls "metadata routing".

There are 2 required steps which are missing in your example:

- opting in by running `sklearn.set_config(enable_metadata_routing=True)`
- explicitly telling `scikit-learn` to pass through `eval_set` and `callbacks`, via `.set_fit_request()`.

([docs link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/metadata_routing.html#metadata-routing))

Consider this minimal, reproducible example using Python 3.11, `lightgbm==4.3.0`, and `scikit-learn==1.4.1`.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

# enable metadata_routing
sklearn.set_config(enable_metadata_routing=True)

# create datasets
X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_blobs(
    n_samples=10_000,
    n_features=10,
    centers=2
)
eval_dataset = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
eval_results = {}

# construct estimator
params = {
    "objective": "binary",
    "n_estimators": 10,
}
fit_params = {
    "eval_set": (X, y),
    "callbacks": [lgb.record_evaluation(eval_results)]
}

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(
    lgb.LGBMClassifier(**params)
    .set_fit_request(callbacks=True, eval_set=True)
)

# train
clf.fit(X, y,  **fit_params)

# check eval results, to prove that the callback was used
print(eval_results)

# {'valid_0': OrderedDict([('binary_logloss', [0.598138869381609, 0.5203293282602738, 0.45544446427154844, 0.40059849184355334, 0.3537472248673818, 0.31338812592304066, 0.2783839141567028, 0.24785302530927006, 0.22109850424011224, 0.19756016345789282])])}
```